# Angular : How to get value in html passing to other component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to send value which I'm getting from web service to another component but the problem is that I'm getting empty value in that another component while I can see that the value is present when I do console.log() in the current component.

**AppComponent**

**ts**

```
level: string = '';

getCustomer(id: string) {
    this.isLoading = true;

        this.customerService.getOne(id)
            .subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    this.level = data.level;
                    console.log(this.level); // Here I can see the value
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.errorMessage = error;
                },
            );
      }
```

**html**

```
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <app-other-component [active]="level"></app-other-component> 
    </div>
```

**AppOtherComponent**

**ts**

```
@Input() active: string;

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.active); // Here I'm getting an empty string
  }
```

I think that this line is executing `<app-other-component [active]="level"></app-other-component>`before the value of 'level' is even filled.

How can I resolve this? thanks.

Comment: Probably because the call to get the data is async and it its not yet present at the time the `ngOnInit()` is called

Comment: You will have to implement `OnChanges` to get the updated value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping the div in an `*ngIf`, if you don't want the `app-other-component` to be visible before the value is set from the web service:

```
<div class="col-lg-8" *ngIf="level">
  <app-other-component [active]="level"></app-other-component> 
</div>
```

And yeah as Yousef suggested, you will get the updated `@Input` value in `ngOnChanges` and NOT IN `ngOnInit`. `ngOnChanges` is the function that gets called on a component every time one of its `@Input` property changes. So you'll get the updated `@Input` property in there:

```
@Input() active: string;

ngOnChanges() {
  console.log(this.active); // Here You'll get the updated `active` string.
}
```

Comment: But if he need the component rendered when the `level` is not setted your answer is not quite good.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, I think that's something that he'll have to explicitly specify in the OP. We can't just assume that right? :)

Comment: @SiddAjmera Thanks! it worked perfectly in my situation

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is because of 'this' pointer in callback function (which does not point to the component). Change it to 'self' like that

```
let self = this;
this.customerService.getOne
...
(data) => { self.level = data.level; }
```